# Writing Lon,Lat coordinates to a shapefile in Matlab with projection

Tags: matlab, arcgis

I have a list of longitude and latitude points that plot an object moving over time on a map; it sort of forms a line that curves around a bit.  I am using Matlab to generate these points and would like to export them into a polyline shapefile to load in ArcGIS.

After looking at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/f20-15124.html#f20-12334) example from the mathworks website, I am able to create a line geostruct object:

```
[Tracks(1:length(myLon)-1).Geometry] = deal('Line');
trackType = 'gc';
[Tracks.Type] = deal(trackType);
for i = 1:(length(myLon)-1)
    [Tracks(i).Lon Tracks(i).Lat] = track2(trackType, myLon(i, 1), myLat(i, 1), myLon(i+1, 1), myLat(i+1, 1));
end

shapewrite(Tracks, 'path_line');
```

This generally works fine but Geostruct does not contain any type of projection, although the documentation claims Mapstruct does.  Unfortunately I don't see any examples or functions on how to create a Mapstruct.  Does anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Also, I tried to create a Point Geostruct instead of a line using the mathworks example, but it doesn't generate the .dbf file, only .shp and .shx files.  Is there any explanation for this?  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use the "define projection" tool in arcgis to define the projection of your imported polyline. This should create a corresponding .prj file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have at least one 'attribute' in the geostruct other than the lat and lon and geometry values for the .dbf file to be created

Answer (score 0):

I know that is too late, but... Using Matlab 2020, you need to create the .prj file using the next procedure (in this example I use points):

```
pts(:,1) = data.X;  % Longitude data
pts(:,2) = data.Y;  % Latitude data

% Creating a structure where we will save the spatial data
dats = struct();

% Knowing the number of point to export
[r,~] = size(pts);

% Setting the geographic entity
[dats(1:r).Geometry] = deal('Point');

% Building the attributes table
for i = 1 : r
    dats(i).Lon = pts(i,1);
    dats(i).Lat = pts(i,2);
    dats(i).Name = horzcat('Pt',num2str(i));
end

% Exporting the data to shapefile
shapewrite(dats,'test.shp'));

% Setting the CRS
proj = geocrs(4326,'Authority','EPSG'); % WGS84

% Wkt string
srtWkt = wktstring(proj,'Version','wkt1');

% Creating the projecting data
fid = fopen('test.prj'),'w');
fprintf(fid,srtWkt);
fclose all;
```

With this example, you will get the *.shp, *.dbf, *.shx and *.prj files that you can use in QGIS.

[My answer is based on this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/898412-how-to-create-geostructure-from-lat-lon-geocrs)

Another example is using a polyline and table to create a shapefile with its projection. This code only would run with Matlab 2021b:

```
ptos(:,1) = data.X;
ptos(:,2) = data.Y;

Shape = geolineshape(ptos(:,2),ptos(:,1));
proy = geocrs(4326,'Authority','EPSG');
Shape.GeographicCRS = proy;

Name = {'Polyline01'};

geota = table(Shape,Name);

shapewrite(geota,horzcat('test,'.shp'));

srtWkt = wktstring(proy,'Version','wkt1');
fid = fopen(horzcat('test','.prj'),'w');
fprintf(fid,srtWkt);
fclose all;

wmline(geota);
```